# Camera Preview does not fill entire screen when using Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

In the second picture I created a stand alone camera app and everything works correctly. However, when I transplanted the app into another app I started to see issues with the Camera preview not filling the entire screen. The only difference I know of is that the one that works correctly uses and activity instead of a fragment.

My Camera preview layout looks like the following in both applications.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipChildren="false">

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/camera_crosshairs"
                 android:layout_margin="7dip"
            >

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:id="@+id/validationSection"
                  android:background="@color/richRed">


        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/notLevel"
                  android:background="@color/richRed"
                  android:text="@string/notLevel"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:padding="10dip"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/pictureSection">
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_remove"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:id="@+id/confirmSection">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_use"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Use"
            style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton"
            />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_retake"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Retake"
            style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: How it looks]

[image: How it is supposed to look]

Comment: Can I see the framelayout to which you add the fragment? I guess that something is wrong with that...

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are asking for. The code I posted is the previewxml. There is a FrameLayout in there with an ID of camer_preview. I then do the following. `mPreview = new W2CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);`

Comment: I mean, you thought you use fragment in the second application, right? Normally fragments has a layout, which you add via FragmentManager the activity layout, when you instantiate the fragment. If this layout is the one used for the fragment, which do you use for your activity?

Comment: Thanks for the insight! In the new application I was inheriting from an abstract base activity that had multiple placeholders for other fragments. My camera fragment was getting stuck in a scrollview and among other fragment placeholders that had the wrap content attribute. I have fixed it now!. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was inheriting from a BaseActivity. The BaseActivity was inserting my CameraFragment into the center of a layout that had a wrap content attribute. I created a new abstract class, that would allow my camera to be the only fragment on the screen and used the fill_parent attribute. Everything is working nicely now.